# unable to create a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client

I have following code which compares user input

```
import thread,sys
if(username.get_text() == 'xyz' and password.get_text()== '123' ):
   thread.start_new_thread(run,()) 

def run():
  print "running client"
  start = datetime.now().second
  while True:
    try:
        host ='localhost'
        port = 5010
        time = abs(datetime.now().second-start)
        time = str(time)
        print time
        client = socket.socket()
        client.connect((host,port))
        client.send(time)
    except socket.error:
        pass
```

If I just call the function run() it works but when I try to create a thread to run this function, for some reason the thread is not created and run() function is not executed I am unable to find any error..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you provide a minimal running example? This code won't run because the names `username` and `password` aren't defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you really should use the `threading` module instead of `thread`.

what else are you doing? if you create a thread like this, then the interpreter will exit no matter if the thread is still running or not

for example:

```
import thread
import time

def run():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('ok')

thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
```

--> this produces:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

where as:

```
import threading
import time

def run():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('ok')

t=threading.Thread(target=run)
t.daemon = True  # set thread to daemon ('ok' won't be printed in this case)
t.start()
```

works as expected. if you don't want to keep the interpreter waiting for the thread, just set daemon=True* on the generated Thread.

*edit: added that in example

Comment: I knew that thread.start_new_thread is a limited library and I initially used threading.thread, thread was created and run function was also called, but the problem was that the code was struck in while loop. There the whole purpose of thread is defeated, so I tried using thread.start_new_thread. In a nutshell my problem is still not solved. when I create a thread in my code, the code is getting struck in while loop. Also please try to solve my code, I know run() definition given by you is simple and it works.

Comment: of course it's stuck in a loop. if you don't want that, you must have a way to end the thread in some way.
[this](http://pastebin.com/YcRnyEbK) works by setting the thread to be a daemon thread which means it will be killed when no other (non-deamon) threads are running.

Comment: can you please explain that wid some code, i have heard about daemon thread but don kno how to use it..
thnx for replyin

Answer (score 0):

`thread` is a low level library, you should use [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).

```
from threading import Thread
t = Thread(target=run, args=())
t.start()
```